# Why would one have to exit twice when leaving an ssh bash connection?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh

When connected through SSH, a machine requires that I exit twice before returning to the local computer's shell;  is there a reason why this happens, it doesn't seem like it should work that way.

Comment: I have never seen/experienced this myself. Could you possibly include more information about the server in your question?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a MacPro Early 2008...that's about it...

Comment: You would have to exit twice to exit the SSH session if you have started an interactive shell on top of the one you got via `ssh` (started, either manually or via one of your shell's startup files). You don't mention anything about your  shells's configuration.

Comment: I often have to "exit" twice when I log into my vps, but that's because I login using a script that automatically connects me to a screen I have running there, so I first have to detach from that screen and then exit the SSH session.

Comment: @Henrik Unless you need to do other things in your script once `screen` has terminated, you may use `exec screen` to _replace_ the script process with `screen`.

Comment: he never mentioned he is using `screen`.

Comment: The OP never mentioned anything that could explain this, that's why I added a comment with a possible explanation. (And I just checked, my script is local and executes `screen` on the vps instead of a shell, the reason I press `^d` twice when logging out is simply that I always want to close the xterm, so not the described problem, but it could due to `screen`)

Comment: @Henrik I'll have to look; I'm sure it's not using tmux as I normally start that manually, maybe I was playing with screen on it a long time ago and just forgot it was there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would happen if you started a new interactive shell on top of the one started by `ssh`.  A new shell would be started if you, for example, executed `screen` or `tmux` (or `bash` or some other shell for that matter) from you shell's startup files (e.g. `~/.bash_profile` for `bash`), or from some system wide shell startup file in `/etc`.

Starting `screen` or `tmux` from there would temporarily "suspend" the startup of the initial shell while the other process is running.  Once you exit `screen` or `tmux`, the initial shell session would give you a new prompt that you would have to exit from separately.

To work around this, instead of just using `screen` or `tmux`, use `exec screen` or `exec tmux`.  This would *replace* the current shell with the appropriate process.

If you do it this way, make sure that no further setup is needed after the call to `exec` as this call will never return the control to the startup script (unless an error occurs in executing `exec`).

This is an example from my own `~/.profile` file (I don't use `bash`) for starting `tmux` when I log in:

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ] && [ -z "$DISPLAY" ]; then
    if tmux has-session; then
        exec tmux attach-session
    else
        exec tmux
    fi
fi
```

This would replace the current shell with `tmux` if the shell session was not already running in a `tmux` session (`TMUX` would be set if it was), and also if we're not in a graphical environment (`DISPLAY` would be set if we were).  If there exists a `tmux` session, this session is attached, otherwise a new one is started.